# Is there a keyboard shortcut to remove link preview in Facebook chat?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, facebook-messenger

It's very common when pasting a URL in the Facebook chat window that a preview is automatically generated. It's possible to remove that preview by clicking on the on the `x` in the top-right corner.

I'm currently able to trigger a click on that element by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> ten times to set focus on it, and then <kbd>Space</kbd> to trigger a click, but is there a keyboard shortcut or some keyboard way to delete this preview that doesn't depend on the user interface having an exact number clickable elements?

Typical scenario on the left, after tabbing a specific number of times to focus on the "remove preview" element on the right:

[image: Facebook chat window showing generated link preview] [image: Facebook chat window with focus on link preview remove element]